# Consuming OAuth2 protected API with Spring Security & Webclient in Servlet environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to consume some protected Rest APIs in my latest version of Spring Boot Application. APIs that are gonna be accessed require **authorization_code** grant type.

As far as I can see, Spring Security provides 2 kinds of DSL

- oauth2Login()
- oauth2Client()

Without any custom security configuration, after adding `ClientRegistration` properties into my application.properties file, Spring configured by default below filters.

- WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
- SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
- HeaderWriterFilter
- CsrfFilter
- LogoutFilter
- OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
- OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
- OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
- DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
- DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
- RequestCacheAwareFilter
- SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
- AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
- OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter
- SessionManagementFilter
- ExceptionTranslationFilter
- FilterSecurityInterceptor

What is still not clear to me is that I actually don't want to secure my own API, I want to initialize oauth2 flow when actually I request the 3rd party API.
Should I use `oauth2Login()` and start the flow even before I consume the 3rd party API ? So when I actually start consuming, I would have a valid Authentication in my context that WebClient can take and add necessary headers/params to the request. Or it is a totally false assumption?
What are the subtle differences between these 2 DSLs?

Comment: `oauth2Client()` is for calling the REST API of the resource server. `oauth2Login()` is for Single Sign On with OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.

Comment: @dur So, It means, I can initiate the flow even without `oauth2Login()`  by just configuring `oauth2Client()` ?

Comment: It dependy on your grant type. With client credential grant type it is possible. If you want to impersonate you need a log in of your user.

Comment: @dur my grant type is authorization_code, so it means, I should use `oauth2Login()` and initiate the flow even before I hit the 3rd party API, right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.